# Unintentional space in DataGrid Header columns in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have unmeant space in my DataGrid between the last Header column and the Header column before last. The background color of the space is like the App background color (#FF454545). The background colors of my Header columns are individually set. Did I ignore something that evokes this issue?

Here is my code:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUserFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding UserFilesObject}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF454545" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="File" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding File}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF454545" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Check" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding LastCheck}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF454545" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Next Check" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding NextCheck}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF454545" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF454545" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Readable">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Not Readable">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="1*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF454545" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Click="btnDgUserFiles_CheckNow_Click">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_refresh}" />
                                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Click="btnDgUserFiles_Delete_Click">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_delete}" />
                                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture to make problem more clear?

Comment: I see the problem only in a designer. At runtime it's ok. Try to detect what the space is via [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Did you add any other styles to the grid?

Comment: No other styles are existent.

Comment: It's not an issue of the Designer. It is the output in debugging mode.